# Why has a release() in unique_ptr? What is the usefulness?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why would someone have a unique_ptr and then later release it? Why not have a raw pointer instead in the first place?

Comment: It's easy to forget that plenty of programmers interface with old libraries or just old code in general. In the engine I use, and libraries I use, including C libraries, it's sometimes required to relinquish the ownership of a pointer to another module or something. Sure I could just create a raw pointer to begin with, but perhaps it won't always be released to some other module.

Comment: Passing ownership to anything that doesn't use unique_ptr, such as some C library is the first thing that comes to mind of why would i use it.

Comment: Protection right up until the pointer is handed over to the new owner has its uses

Comment: If you're using placement new into dynamic memory, it's useful to use a `unique_ptr` to own the memory until the `new` call completes. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b1f67853cced1e3. I vaguely recall doing something like this in a constructor once, but can't recall why.

Answer (score 4):

It is useful for `unique_ptr` to have ownership of a raw pointer until such time that ownership is no longer needed and someone else will take ownership of the pointer (ie, another library, etc).  Until then, the `unique_ptr` can keep the pointer safe and make sure it is still freed even if something unexpected happens, or just if ownership does not get transferred.